# How to write 3 almost equal xpaths more concise

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

**Set-up**

I'm using Selenium to fill in a form.

I have three Xpaths to three different fields in the form,

```
'//*[@id="down-contact-box"]/div[3]/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input'
'//*[@id="down-contact-box"]/div[3]/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/input'
'//*[@id="down-contact-box"]/div[3]/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/input'
```

with only their last `div[]` differing.

---

**Problem**

I'd prefer to do something more concise instead of using them each time

I'm looking for something that allows me to do,

```
def x(i) = '//*[@id="down-contact-box"]/div[3]/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/div[i]/input'
```

such that I only have to write `x(1), x(2)` or `x(3)`.

How do I do this?

Comment: I feel there must be more convenient & convincing way to identify those nodes if you consider to share the relevant `HTML`.

Comment: These XPaths are too long and will be brittle (break easily on document changes). You would get a better answer if you posted a link to the page or the relevant HTML and let us hand craft an XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, that is rather simple.
You could just do this:

```
def x(i):
    return '//*[@id="down-contact-box"]/div[3]/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/div[{}]/input'.format(i)
```